# How to disable IMA UI on iOS

Tags: swift

How to switch off entire UI of IMA (Google Interactive Media Ads)? It can't be customised so I need to turn it off and create my own.

Answer (score 2):

So I could not find any better solution than to search through hierarchy and hide view manually. As IMA uses AVplayer as a container for its own ad player, I need to look through hierarchy of my AVPlayer, find IMAWKWebView and hide it. I am not big fan of this kind of solutions but as I can't find anything better at the moment, here it is:

```
    for view in adContainer.subviews {
        for subView in view.subviews {
            if subView.description.range(of: "IMAWKWebView") != nil {
                subView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Where adContainer is usually your AVPlayer or anything you submit to IMAAdDisplayContainer.

I call this on STARTED event in IMAAdsManagerDelegate. It works well, however, even if I can't reproduce it now but I think it showed original UI after start for a while.